# How to get POST body in ESP8266 micropython server

Tags: python, esp8266, micropython

I am trying to create a simple Micropython project where when the microcontroller first turns on, if it is unsuccessful at connecting to wifi, it will begin to host an Access Point. When connected to the access point, the device serves a simple webpage that allows to user to enter their SSID and Passphrase, which are then stored to the device for future use.

I am having a problem, however, with retrieving the values that the user types into the webpage after the form is submitted. This is my code:

```
import ujson as json
import usocket as socket
import network
import time

max_wifi_retry = 30

class ConnectWifi:
    # Constructor retrieves stored credentials and saves them to class variables
    def __init__(self, credentialsFile='config.json'):
        with open(credentialsFile) as fp:
            config = json.load(fp)
            self.ssid = config["ssid"]
            self.password = config["password"]
            self.access_point_ssid = config["access_point_ssid"]
       
    # This method will attempt to connect device to wifi
    def connectWifi(self):
        self.wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    
        #Restarting WiFi
        self.wifi.active(False)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.wifi.active(True)
        
        self.wifi.connect(self.ssid, self.password)
        
        if not self.wifi.isconnected():
            print('connecting')
            wifi_retry_attempts = 0
            while not self.wifi.isconnected() and wifi_retry_attempts < max_wifi_retry:
                print(max_wifi_retry - wifi_retry_attempts)
                wifi_retry_attempts += 1
                time.sleep_ms(1000)
                
        if not self.wifi.isconnected():
            self.wifi.active(False)
                
        return self.wifi.isconnected()
    
    # This is where I am having trouble knowing what to do
    def enableAccessPoint(self):
        print('Unable to connect to wifi, enabling wireless access point config')
        ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
        ap.active(True)
        ap.config(essid=self.access_point_ssid, authmode=network.AUTH_OPEN)
        
        print(ap.ifconfig())
        
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', 80))
        s.listen(5)
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
                request = conn.recv(1024)
                print('Content = %s' % str(request))
                response = self.getWebPage()
                conn.send(response)
                conn.close()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("break")
                break
            
    def getWebPage(self):
        html = """
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>Configure Wifi</h1>
                        <form action="/submit" method="post">
                          <label for="ssid">SSID:</label><br>
                          <input name="SSID" type="text" id="ssid" value=""><br><br>
                          <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
                          <input name="PASSWORD" type="text" id="password" value=""><br><br>
                          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </body>
                </html>
                """
        return html
```

In short to quickly explain the issue, I have this socket that is created and listens for requests:

```
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', 80))
        s.listen(5)
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
                request = conn.recv(1024)
                print('Content = %s' % str(request))
                response = self.getWebPage()
                conn.send(response)
                conn.close()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("break")
                break
```

I am trying to figure out how to modify the code above in order to identify which page the user has requested, and also read any form params when the user submits the form, is this possible?

Here is the HTML form for reference.

```
<html>
                    <head>
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>Configure Wifi</h1>
                        <form action="/submit" method="post">
                          <label for="ssid">SSID:</label><br>
                          <input name="SSID" type="text" id="ssid" value=""><br><br>
                          <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
                          <input name="PASSWORD" type="text" id="password" value=""><br><br>
                          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: When you print out the value returned by `request = conn.recv(1024)`, what do you see? Are you certain that the request will fit within 1024 bytes? Do you understand what an [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) looks like?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/belyalov/tinyweb/blob/master/tinyweb/server.py) may be of interest.

Comment: @larsks The value returned looks like this:



b'GET /submit?SSID=Djxjdk&PASSWORD=Fjdjd HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.4.1\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'



I did change it to a GET method instead of a POST, so I can see the values in the request!

Comment: @larsks The problem now is that I'm using regex to try and parse out the inputs, which is just really ugly. I know there is probably a better way to go about this in micropython, but I'm not sure what to do. I really appreciate your input, thank you so much!

Comment: That's one of the reason I provided the link to the micropython webserver implementation: it includes examples of parsing both JSON and `x-www-url-formencoded` POST bodies. In general you shouldn't need regular expressions for this task, but if you'd like to update your answer to show us the code you're currently using we'd be in a better position to offer suggestions.

Comment: Instead of using socket module to create a socket connection, The [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) module defines classes for implementing HTTP servers and make it easier to write a web server application. It is not for production grade of implementation but good enough for you application.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the client request in your buffer, you need to parse it to find the various pieces you're looking for. There are modules out there (like [microdot](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microdot) on GitHub) that will do this for you with MicroPython. Or you can roll your own.

If you choose to do your own, it'll look something like this:

```py
    def parse_query_string(query_string):
        query = {}
        query_params = query_string.split('&')
        for param in query_params:
            if (not '=' in param):  # A key with no value, like: 'red' instead of 'color=red'
                key=param
                query[key] = ''
            else:
                key, value = param.split('=')
                query[key] = value
                
        return query


    def parse_http_request(req_buffer):
        assert (req_buffer != b''), 'Empty request buffer.'

        req = {}
        req_buffer_lines = req_buffer.decode('utf8').split('\r\n')
        req['method'], target, req['http_version'] = req_buffer_lines[0].split(' ', 2)  # Example: GET /route/path HTTP/1.1
        if (not '?' in target):
            req['path'] = target
        else:  # target can have a query component, so /route/path could be something like /route/path?state=on&timeout=30
            req['path'], query_string = target.split('?', 1)
            req['query'] = parse_query_string(query_string)

        req['headers'] = {}
        for i in range(1, len(req_buffer_lines) - 1):
            if (req_buffer_lines[i] == ''):  # Blank line signifies the end of headers.
                break
            else:
                name, value = req_buffer_lines[i].split(':', 1)
                req['headers'][name.strip()] = value.strip()
                
        req['body'] = req_buffer_lines[len(req_buffer_lines) - 1]  # Last line is the body (or blank if no body.)
        
        return req
```

If you take your buffer that you have captured in `request` and pass it to `parse_http_request()` like this:

```py
req = parse_http_request(request)
```

You'll get a dictionary called `req` that has things like headers, body, etc. that you'll need.

When you post form data from the web page, you end up with the query string inside the body. You can use the `parse_query_string()` function to get a python dictionary of the parameters sent. If you set the form method to GET, you'll find your parameters as a dictionary in `req['query'].

Mozilla's developer network has an example of what happens during an HTTP transaction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session

The functions above were pulled from a module called [Thimble](https://github.com/DavesCodeMusings/thimble) that I'm working on to run an API on my ESP devices. You can find more examples on the project's GitHub page that might help you with what you're wanting to do.